# Setting Solarized colors on a Vagrant Ubuntu Box

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I am trying to set the colors of my Ubuntu Box to match the 16 colors palette of the Solarized color theme.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 Server, no GUI option enabled.

When I ssh into this VM and I do a

```
$ echo $ TERM
```

it displays the value `xterm`. So I was guessing I could use .Xresources to set the colors.

But when I enter

```
$ xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

it shows a message which says `No display found`. What does it mean? Does it mean there is no XServer running? Do I have to set the colors by echo'ing color codes in my .bashrc?

Comment: What do you get with `echo $DISPLAY` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring It doesn't display anything.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking properly when I wrote the previous comment. Since your server has no GUI you're working with a simple CLI terminal and there's no X server running. I guess there are various X commands on your HD in case you do want to run X. OTOH, it's weird that $TERM is xterm... Anyway, I've never played with this stuff myself, but you should be able to customize your terminal's palette. Have a look at [setcolors - Change your Linux VT color palette](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168392) - he even provides a colorscheme file for Solarized.

Comment: Also see the man page for [console_codes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html). The `ESC ] Pnrrggbb` codes look promising.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your server has no GUI you're working with a simple CLI terminal and there's no X server running. I guess there are various X commands on your HD in case you do want to run X. OTOH, it's weird that $TERM is xterm...

Anyway, I've never played with this stuff myself, but you *should* be able to customize your terminal's palette. Have a look at [setcolors - Change your Linux VT color palette](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168392) - he even provides a colorscheme file for Solarized.

Also see the man page for console_codes. The `ESC ] Pnrrggbb` codes look promising.